# Temporarily disable Firebase database

Tags: firebase, offline, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there any way to temporarily disable all access to your Firebase database, sort of like a kill switch? I know you can alter the rules so that everything if false, which will restrict anything which doesn't have administrator access, but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I'm not aware of a more elegant solution. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Like I said, something akin to a "kill switch" that would simply disable all read/write abilities with that database until it was toggled back to positive. This could be useful for maintenance or system updates.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent anyone from accessing your database, just set these rules in the rules tab of your database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

The only alternative I can think of is to disable the database altogether, by disabling the API - but that might have unwanted side-effects.

Comment: As I stated in the question, I'm aware of this approach but was hoping of a way that completely disabled access, including those with admin privileges.